# apache2.conf and httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

After reading [ubuntu AMP community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) and [Apache 2.4 configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html).

I was wondering if there is a way to imitate the same behavior of the http docs used in XAMPP or bitnami stacks but using the default LAMP. Which uses apache 2.4

In XAMP you would assign an extra number to your `httpd-vhost.conf` like this:

```
Listen *:9000 
<virtualhost *:9000>  
    ServerName localhost 
    DocumentRoot "~/xamp/apache2/htdocs/html/app-name/" 
</virtualhost> 

<Directory "~/xamp/apache2/htdocs/html/app-name/">  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride all 
</Directory>
```

Then Edit your `httpd.conf` files like:

```
//....Some code.....   */ 
<Directory>
    AllowOverride all
<Directory /> 
//...Some code...
```

and uncomment this line:

```
//....Some code.....   */ 

# Virtual hosts
include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf 

//...Some code...
```

My question is:

Is there is a way to configure Apache 2.4 just by dropping all my vhost's in one single file, without having to go through the process of configuring `etc/apache2/sites-available` and then adding names to `etc/hosts`?

Then completing the process by including some things like above just like Bitnami or Xamp stacks will do so your localhost will be able to serve not only static html files but an entire application's folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works is the following in (for example) your 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.vm

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1/web/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1_access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/site1/web/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.vm

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2/web/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site2_access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/site2/web/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This way all you have to do is add the site to the conf file, add the host to your hosts file, and reload apache2 service. Hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: So if I understood correctly all the default configurations in this file disappear? you just keep the ones you want and the `etc/hosts` will look like:
`127.0.0.1    site1.vm`

Comment: I kept the default values above the virtual hosts and it works great. In etc/hosts I have a line per local site, though they can all be on same line too of course (site1.vm, site2.vm etc).

Comment: Could you please share a template of your conf file please @marcel :) or is this one mod done in `default-000` the only one?  is `apache2.conf`  even touched?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. The only file I adapted is default-000, where is just add all sites I need. And of course the hosts file where the names are mapped to my localhost address.